# Regarding creating new AVD device using Google API

Tags: android, android-virtual-device

[image]

Where am I wrong? Please help me to enable OK button.

[image]

Comment: Works fine on my mac, try choosing another google api version

Comment: Maybe it can't use ARM, choose another CPU architecture

Comment: @Shereef what architecture did you use on your MAC?